# Load Data To tableView Cell from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swift5

I Have array , i want load data to table view cell from that array . But I dont how to do. Any ideas?

```
Array = [{id:1,title:a,desc:abc},{id:2,title:b,desc:abc},{id:3,title:c,desc:abc}]


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return array.count
       }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
           return 100
       }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
       cell.label1.text = "Data from array"
       cell.label2.text = "Data from array"
        return cell!
    }
```

based on the array.count I want display the cells

```
firstcell = array[0]
secondcell = array[1]
thirdcell = array[2]
```

this is what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` asks for a specific cell at `indexPath`, this value contains `row` and `section`

By default table view has single section so you only need `row`:

```
cell.label1.text = array[indexPath.row]
```